# How to get calender for selected date and month only in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to get the datepicket calender for the selected month and year using jquery/javascript.

[image]

for example, if i select the year to 2023 and month january then, the date field should show January 2023 calender only. like mindate is 2023-01-01 and maxdate is 2023-01-31.

I tried some online methods but they are not working though jquery/javascript. Can somebody help me to getting out of this

Comment: wouldn´t it be waaay easier to just have a "day-select" as third input .... ? Or just one datetime input?

Comment: Actually, year and month is coming from database and i have to show only date input according to the year and month.